# Events still being triggered by children despite stopPropagation() and cancelBubble

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a `<div>` element (containing my page header) which has an `onmouseover` event that fades the header into a menu. It also has an `onmouseout` event that does the reverse. The menu itself is simply a bunch of links and images. When the mouse enters the `<div>`, it fades just as expected. However, when I move the mouse between elements *within* the `<div>`, the `onmouseout` event is triggered by the element I'm leaving, followed by the `onmouseover`event of the element I'm entering. I've tried to stop this using `stopPropagation` and `cancelBubble`, but to no avail. Here is the relevant code:

JavaScript (stored in menu.js):

```
//These two functions are for rendering the menu. 
//Fade is a function that fades an element out or in by 
//changing the opacity of the element.

function renderHeader() {
fade('menu');
setTimeout("document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML=\
\"<img src='menu_1.png' width=20% /><img src='menu_2.png' width=20% />\
<img src='menu_3.png' width=20% /><img src='menu_4.png' width=20% />\
<img src='menu_5.png' width=20% />\"",TimeToFade+33);
setTimeout("fade('menu')",TimeToFade+66);
}

function renderMenu() {
fade('menu');
setTimeout("document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML=\
\"<a href='home.asp'><img src='menu_a.png' width=20% /></a>\
<a href='members.asp'><img src='menu_b.png' width=20% /></a>\
<a href='locations.asp'><img src='menu_c.png' width=20% /></a>\
<a href='about.asp'><img src='menu_d.png' width=20% /></a>\
<a href='services.asp'><img src='menu_e.png' width=20% /></a>\"",TimeToFade+33);
setTimeout("fade('menu')",TimeToFade+66);
}


//These two functions are responsible for stopping the propagation.
function load() {
  element = document.getElementById("menu");
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", stopEvent, false);
  element.addEventListener("mouseout", stopEvent, false);
}

function stopEvent(ev) {
  if (!ev) var ev = window.event;
  ev.cancelBubble = true;
  if (ev.stopPropagation) ev.stopPropagation();
}
```

HTML (the `<div>` element initially shows the header):

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/menu.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="load();">
<div id='menu' style="opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);height:150px"
onmouseover="renderMenu()" onmouseout="renderHeader()">
<img src='menu_1.png' width=20% /><img src='menu_2.png' width=20% />
<img src='menu_3.png' width=20% /><img src='menu_4.png' width=20% />
<img src='menu_5.png' width=20% /></div>
```

Comment: You really should consider setting up your timeout calls with actual functions.  (The first argument to "setTimeout()" should be a function and not a string, in other words.)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that was possible. In any case, I've switched over to jQuery at this point, so I'm not using setTimeout anymore.

Answer (score 0):

stopPropagation() can cancelBubble() stop bubbling up, from children to ancestors not bubbling down, since bubbling down never happens to begin with. It is the mouseover and mouseout event on you elements inside your menu that are eventually bubbling up to your menu element. I think something like this might work for you:

```
function load() {
  elements = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName('*');
  elements.addEventListener("mouseover", stopEvent, false);
  elements.addEventListener("mouseout", stopEvent, false);
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be using strings in your setTimeout. Your strings get eval()'d which is very slow compared to just passing in a function. Especially a long string like some of your's. You want:

```
function renderHeader() {
fade('menu');
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML=\
"<img src='menu_1.png' width=20% /><img src='menu_2.png' width=20% />\
<img src='menu_3.png' width=20% /><img src='menu_4.png' width=20% />\
<img src='menu_5.png' width=20% />"; },TimeToFade+33);
setTimeout(function(){ fade('menu'); },TimeToFade+66);
}

function renderMenu() {
fade('menu');
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML=\
"<a href='home.asp'><img src='menu_a.png' width=20% /></a>\
<a href='members.asp'><img src='menu_b.png' width=20% /></a>\
<a href='locations.asp'><img src='menu_c.png' width=20% /></a>\
<a href='about.asp'><img src='menu_d.png' width=20% /></a>\
<a href='services.asp'><img src='menu_e.png' width=20% /></a>"; },TimeToFade+33);
setTimeout(function(){ fade('menu'); },TimeToFade+66);
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I was misunderstanding _what_ was propagating. It's the event itself, not the event handler.
In any case, your solution didn't work for me. I've switched over to jQuery (so much easier!), but it's still not working. Shouldn't these two lines (in the head) just about cover it?
`$("*").mouseenter(function(event){event.stopPropagation();});
 $("*").mouseleave(function(event){event.stopPropagation();});`

Comment: I also tried using .live() and .bind(), and they're not working either - 
`$("*").live("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event){event.stopPropagation();});` and `$("*").bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event){event.stopPropagation();});`. Nor do they work with mouseover and mouseout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're only attaching the handler to the outer "menu" element.  The fact that its handler cancels propagation doesn't matter; by that time it's too late.

What you can do instead is check the "target" property of the event, and only respond when it's the right element.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Pointy. As you'll see in my comments in the above answer, I've now switch over to jQuery, but am still having the same problems.

Comment: Well, @err1100, it doesn't matter *how* you bind the handlers. You'll still get events bubbling up, because that's what browsers do.

Comment: I understand that. See my comments on PaulPRO's answer for a description of the current problem.